# How to get the inverse data set from a .filter() function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider this json object :

```
const animals = [
 {name: "Bruno", type: "dog"},
 {name: "Kira", type: "tiger"},
 {name: "Max", type: "dog"},
 {name: "Gogo", type: "parrot"},
 {name: "Hixon", type: "dog"}
]
```

To get all the dogs we could apply .filter() as follows :

```
const dogs = animals.filter((animal) => {
 if (animal.type === "dog") {
  return animal;
 }
)
```

Which is the best practise to get the inverse data set ? In this case the rest of animal types ?

Answer (score 3):

You're not using `filter` as intended - the callback it receives is meant to return `true` or `false` depending on whether or not the item should be in the set. An object is classed as a 'truthy' item by JavaScript, so your code still works, but it ought to look more like this:

```
const dogs = animals.filter(animal => animal.type === "dog");
```

Looking at this, it's probably a lot clearer how you're meant to invert the set!

```
const notDogs = animals.filter(animal => animal.type !== "dog");
```